# how to create a join feature in php with a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

hello im new to php so the scenario is this:

I have created a login/logout feature and an event page, on the event page, there is a join button next to each event.

I want to decrease an int value (expected number of people) in a mysql database when the user clicks the join button.

How would I go about doing this? my problem is that i do not know how to associate each button to its corresponding event.

The events are dynamically created by other users.

The following is the javascript within the  tags

```
$("button").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "decrease.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: { id : id },

            });

            request.done(function( msg ) {
                $( "#log" ).html( msg );
            });

            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
            });
        });
    });
```

The following is the file decrease.php:

```
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost");
define('DB_USER', "root");
define('DB_PASSWORD', "");
define('DB_TABLE', "bong");

$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_TABLE);

if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . mysqli_connect_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}


if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    //$id = $_POST['id'];
    $id = $_REQUEST["id"];

}

$mysqli->query("UPDATE `events` SET `Eppl` = `Eppl` - 1 WHERE `Eid` = '$id'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is put data-field of event as id like

```
<div class="formgroup">    
    <div data-id='26'><!-- of event --></div>
    <button>join</button>
</div>
```

now with every join click you can parse data-id of related div (For eg. Previous div or same parent child div) so you will get id then do further process.

Comment: I'm sorry but could you please elaborate

Comment: this is what I have done following your advice:                                           echo "<td><div data-id = '$row->Ename'> <button type='button' onclick=''>Join!</button></div></td>";

Comment: I am pulling the event details from a mysql database and displaying them in a tabular format with the button being in the last column

Comment: oh okay I think I know how to do this, correct me if I am wrong but can I simply create a php funciton that uses the data-id to parse the event in the mysql database and then do the manipulation?

Comment: now you go. so on ajax request / form submit  you will get event ID , search the event and take logged in user id and do you task. like adding to Database event_user table

Comment: I have added my recent work following your advice, please take a look at it